# Как в питоне реализовать удаление программы в Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows-10

То есть мне надо написать код на Python 3, который должен **удалять** определенную программу в Windows 10. Такое вообще возможно?))

Это невозможно, да??))) Не молчите главное, пожалуйста))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью `bat-файла` всё возможно.

Удаление без участия пользователя:

```
import os

path = 'file.bat'

with open(path, 'w') as f:
    s = 'wmic product where name="{}" call uninstall /nointeractive'.format('Название программы')
    f.write(s)

os.startfile(path)
```

С участием пользователя:

```
import os

path = 'file.bat'

with open(path, 'w') as f:
    s = 'wmic product where name="{}" call uninstall'.format('Название программы')
    f.write(s)

os.startfile(path)
```

Главное, использовать это не во вред.

Comment: А если программа была установлена не установщиком windows? И вылазит надпись "отсутствуют экземпляры"?

Comment: То есть мне надо удалить программу НЕ wmic.